# OnBlur blocking the save event angular 15

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, primeng, angular15

I have an angular reactive form with various fields, there is one field on which I have kept an onBlur event to call API from the backend.
The problem is sometimes if I type something in that field and without removing focus click on the save button the event on onBlur is fired and API is called but the save function is not called after that.

What could be the reason and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Could you please share some piece of code blocks of your reactive form, onBlur function and save function?